# Passthrough Promises, does the function need to be async?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

The question is: Does a javascript function that is simply a pass-through function need to be marked as async.
This is the original code marked as async with an await.  Sonar is flagging the await as redundant.  So I removed the await, but my question is does this function need to be flagged async because it is not doing anything async.  It is now a simple pass-through function.

```
private async getResponse(url: string): Promise<HttpResponse> {
    const axiosConfig = new AxiosRequestConfig();
    axiosConfig.method = HttpMethod.Get;
    const response = new HttpResponse(url, axiosConfig);
    return await response.sendRequest(new HttpRequestOptions(null));
}
```

This is what I updated to but am not sure it is correct.  The code does not error when running tests.

```
private getResponse(url: string, options: HttpRequestOptions): Promise<HttpResponse> {
    const httpSettings = this.getHttpSettings(options);
    const fullUrl = this.isAbsolutUrl(url) ? url : `${httpSettings.getBaseAddress()}${url}`;
    const axiosConfig = new AxiosRequestConfig(httpSettings);
    const response = new HttpResponse(fullUrl, axiosConfig);
    return response.sendRequest(options);
 }
```

This is the sendRequest that is being called it is returning a promise and is marked async so I think it covers the calling method from being marked async.

```
export class HttpResponse { 
  public async sendRequest(options: HttpRequestOptions): Promise<HttpResponse> {
    try {
      switch (options.method) {
        case HttpMethod.Post:
          this._response = await axios.post(this.url, options.body, this.config);
          break;

        case HttpMethod.Get:
          this._response = await axios.get(this.url, this.config);
          break;

        default:
          break;
      }
      this._statusCode = this.response.status;
      this._headers = this.response.headers;
    } catch (error) {
      this.logger.error(error);
      this._error = error;
    }
    return this;
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: The only difference is if any of the methods and constructor you call are throwing an exception (synchronously). If they never do, the two snippets are absolutely equivalent, and I'd avoid an unnecessary `async`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to mark a function as `async` if you use `await` inside it.

Using `await` to get a value that you immediately return is pointless.

So looking at your original function:

> ```
> private async getResponse(url: string): Promise<HttpResponse> {
>     const axiosConfig = new AxiosRequestConfig();
>     axiosConfig.method = HttpMethod.Get;
>     const response = new HttpResponse(url, axiosConfig);
>     return await response.sendRequest(new HttpRequestOptions(null));
> }
> ```

You have `return await ...` so the `await` is pointless.

If you remove that you aren't using `await` at all so there's no point in using `async`.

Comment: The one cavaet to `return await` being pointless is that if it's in a `try` block, it's not pointless; it ensures that the `try` block's associated `catch` (if any) is triggered if the awaited promise rejects, and its `finally` (if any) isn't run until the promise settles. But at the top level of the function (or otherwise outside a `try`), it is indeed pointless. :-)